# Populate fields in SAS by ID and Date

Tags: macros, sas, retain, locf

My dataset looks like this:

```
AsAtDate  ReleaseDate ID Var1 Var2 ... Var5
200701     200601      1   x    .    
200702     200601      1   .    a
200703     200601      1   .    .
200701     200702      2   .    b 
200702     200702      2   y    b
200703     200702      2   y    .
200702     200501      3   z    .
200703     200501      3   .    .
```

I want my results to look like this:

```
AsAtDate  ReleaseDate ID Var1 Var2 ... Var5
200701     200601      1   x    a    
200702     200601      1   x    a
200703     200601      1   x    a
200701     200702      2   .    . 
200702     200702      2   y    b
200703     200702      2   y    b
200702     200501      3   z    .
200703     200501      3   z    .
```

How do I get my data to consider the ReleaseDate as in, if ReleaseDate is earlier than AsAtDate then populate the fields by ID.

Comment: Please post whatever you're tried. You're likely looking at a sort and retain here. Is it possible to have different values?

Comment: @Reeza I tried sort and retain but I can't seem to get it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your solution, we can add a CASE statement to conditionally fill in the data as needed.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *, 
       case when ReleaseDate>AsAtDate then " " 
       else max(Var1) 
       end as _Var1
from have
group by ID
order by ID, AsAtdate;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code, is there a more simplified code than this?

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *, max(Var1) as _Var1
from have
group by ID
order by ID, AsAtdate;
quit;

data want1;
set want;
by id;
if ReleaseDate > AsAtDate then _Var1='';
run;
```

Comment: you could probably add the last step into the PROC SQL query using a CASE statement, but other than that it seems pretty compact.